# Vue JS style binding on the Body Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I've got this whole theme system in my front-end
its based on changing CSS Variables with a mixin to change colours:

```
  --sysPrimary: #03d5f7;
  --sysSecondary: #05fcac;
  --sysHover: #76D9F5;
  --sysWarning: #ff4146;
  --sysBackground: #23242c;
  --sysDarkbackground: #202228;
  --sysInputBg: #494b54;
  --sysGrey: #bbbbbb;
  --sysText: #ffffff;

  --menuPrimary: #03d5f7;
  --menuSecondary: #05fcac;
  --menuHover: #76D9F5;
  --menuText: #000000;
  --menuTextHover: #000000;
  --menuIcons: #000000;
  --menuIconsHover: #000000;
```

So with a click of a button I choose a key, and the css varibles change accordingly

```
_systemStyles() {
            return {
                '--sysPrimary': this._colorTheme.primary,
                '--sysSecondary': this._colorTheme.secondary,
                '--sysHover': this._colorTheme.hover,
                '--sysWarning': this._colorTheme.warning,
                '--sysBackground': this._colorTheme.bg,
                '--sysDarkBackground': this._colorTheme.darkBg,
                '--sysText': this._colorTheme.text,
                '--sysGrey': this._colorTheme.grey,

                '--menuPrimary': this._colorTheme.menu_primary,
                '--menuSecondary': this._colorTheme.menu_secondary,
                '--menuHover': this._colorTheme.menu_hover,
                '--menuText': this._colorTheme.menu_text,
                '--menuTextHover': this._colorTheme.menu_text_hover,
                '--menuIcons': this._colorTheme.menu_icons,
                '--menuIconsHover': this._colorTheme.menu_icons_hover,
            }
        },
```

All I do is `:style="_systemStyles"` in my app.vue file and that's it...everything is automated.

Now, a problem occurs when I use a third party library which renders HTML elements on my `<body></body>` tag.
Since my app is nested inside my body, only elements that are nested inside my app are affected by my CSS variables changing.
Since that library appends on the body level...it only gets the root definition of the variables.

I need a way to style-bind my body element with my _systemStyles Object.

Things I've tried:

getting the body element and trying to override its style with my object - does not compute

importing my scss file on the server where I render the app - nothing really happens its out of scope

that's it basically...I can't think of another solution.

And yes of course I googled, this a complicated issue...

Answer (score 0):

````
            ```document.body.style = `--sysPrimary:${this.COLOR_THEME.primary};--sysSecondary:${this.COLOR_THEME.secondary};--sysHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.hover};--sysWarning:${this.COLOR_THEME.warning};--sysBackground:${this.COLOR_THEME.bg};--sysDarkBackground:${this.COLOR_THEME.darkBg};--sysText:${this.COLOR_THEME.text};--sysGrey:${this.COLOR_THEME.grey};--menuPrimary:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_primary};--menuSecondary:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_secondary};--menuHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_hover};--menuText:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_text};--menuTextHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_text_hover};--menuIcons:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_icons};--menuIconsHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_icons_hover}`;```
````

parse a normal style string using interpolation to override the body style

I am using a watcher to get the current theme key and override a theme object in a data - this way i can access it through both the JS and CSS together :)

My boss ended up coming with the solution. quite neat and clean

````
       '$store.state.menu.themeKey': {
           handler(newVal) {
               if (newVal === this.COLOR_THEME.key) return;
               this.COLOR_THEME = {
                   ...this.COLOR_SETS.find(theme => theme.key === newVal),
                   //shared across all sets
                   darkBg: '#202228',
                   warning: '#ff4146',
                   grey: '#bbbbbb',
               };
               document.body.style = `--sysPrimary:${this.COLOR_THEME.primary};--sysSecondary:${this.COLOR_THEME.secondary};--sysHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.hover};--sysWarning:${this.COLOR_THEME.warning};--sysBackground:${this.COLOR_THEME.bg};--sysDarkBackground:${this.COLOR_THEME.darkBg};--sysText:${this.COLOR_THEME.text};--sysGrey:${this.COLOR_THEME.grey};--menuPrimary:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_primary};--menuSecondary:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_secondary};--menuHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_hover};--menuText:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_text};--menuTextHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_text_hover};--menuIcons:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_icons};--menuIconsHover:${this.COLOR_THEME.menu_icons_hover}`;
           },
           immediate: true,
       }
   },```
````